# How we can analyse graph Hits Per Second and graph Response Time vs Request in html report of Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

When i am mouse hovering on Hits Per Sec graph, it showing

```
HitsPerSec at 17.17.00 was 18.57hits/sec.
```

so i understood at that time, requests per sec was 18.57.And when i am mouse hovering on graph Response Time vs Request, it showing

```
Success median response time at 644req/sec was 1141 ms.
```

Here i am confusing with 644erq/sec and 18.57hits/sec in Hits Per Sec graph.Both are contradicting each other for me.Can anyone give a detailed clarification on this?Thanks in advance.